Changing TIFF image compression type while preserving all tags
Is there a command line tool that will change the type of compression used in a TIFF image without discarding unknown tags? Imagemagick 7.1.1-36 discards GeoTIFF tags when I do the following, despite this post implying otherwise.
% magick USGS_13_n35w119_20240207.tif -compress Zip USGS_13_n35w119_20240207zip.tif

Here’s a sample image. I’m trying to do this on macOS.

You should be able to change the compression with ImageMagick and then use exiftool -TagsFromFile to copy forward the tags. See https://exiftool.org/forum/index.php?topic=10189.0

Post your tiff file here so I can test or report this on the Imagemagick GIF web site.  What is your OS/platform?

Your image link gives "Access denied".

You can just drag and drop the image from your desktop, it'll get picked up by SE's image host.

@MadPhysicist It's pretty hard to see "Is there a command line tool..." as something other than "Question asking us to recommend or find a tool" -- i.e. off-topic.

@DanMašek. Not necessarily. OP is asking for a very specific operation, has clearly done some research, tried something, and has a conflict with current state of knowledge. If I was writing a bash pipeline to do this, I would think of this the same as a python library call

I've fixed image access.

TL,DR
Compress with ImageMagick and copy forward tags from original file with exiftool:
# Compress with ImageMagick
magick INPUT.TIF -compress LZW result.tif
# Copy forward tags from original
exiftool -TagsFromFile INPUT.TIF result.tif

Or, you can make a one-liner:
magick INPUT.TIF -compress lzw TIFF:- | exiftool -TagsFromFile INPUT.TIF - > result.tif

Original Answer
I downloaded a file with GeoTIFF tags from here. I then LZW compressed it with ImageMagick:
magick SP27GTIF.TIF -compress LZW new.tif

magick: Unknown field with tag 33550 (0x830e) encountered. `TIFFReadDirectory' @ warning/tiff.c/TIFFWarnings/945.
magick: Unknown field with tag 33922 (0x8482) encountered. `TIFFReadDirectory' @ warning/tiff.c/TIFFWarnings/945.
magick: Unknown field with tag 34735 (0x87af) encountered. `TIFFReadDirectory' @ warning/tiff.c/TIFFWarnings/945.
magick: Unknown field with tag 34737 (0x87b1) encountered. `TIFFReadDirectory' @ warning/tiff.c/TIFFWarnings/945.

Then I checked the file new.tif and the tags were missing. I put the tags back by copying forward from the original file with with exiftoool:
exiftool -TagsFromFile SP27GTIF.TIF new.tif

And, on checking again, the original GeoTIFF tags (from SP27GTIF.TIF) were present in the LZW-compressed image new.tif .
identify -verbose new.tif | grep -Ei "tag|LZW"

  Format: TIFF (Tagged Image File Format)
identify: Unknown field with tag 33550 (0x830e) encountered. `TIFFReadDirectory' @ warning/tiff.c/TIFFWarnings/945.
identify: Unknown field with tag 33922 (0x8482) encountered. `TIFFReadDirectory' @ warning/tiff.c/TIFFWarnings/945.
identify: Unknown field with tag 34735 (0x87af) encountered. `TIFFReadDirectory' @ warning/tiff.c/TIFFWarnings/945.
identify: Unknown field with tag 34737 (0x87b1) encountered. `TIFFReadDirectory' @ warning/tiff.c/TIFFWarnings/945.
  Compression: LZW

Checking with tiffinfo gives, among other things:
  Tag 33550: 32.800000,32.800000,0.000000
  Tag 33922: 0.000000,0.000000,0.000000,681480.000000,1913050.000000,0.000000
  Tag 34735: 1,0,2,5,1024,0,1,1,1025,0,1,1,1026,34737,24,0,2049,34737,23,24,3072,0,1,26771
  Tag 34737: State Plane NAD27, Feet|NAD27 in Feet default"|
  Predictor: horizontal differencing 2 (0x2)


This is great, thank you. Although I'm trying to go from lzw to zip/deflate.

A colleague suggested gdal_translate for GeoTIFF images. After some experimentation, I settled on this:
% gdal_translate -co compress=deflate -co tiled=yes -co blockxsize=512 -co blockysize=512 -co num_threads=8 

By default, gdal_translate will change a tiled image to one made up of strips, so you have to be explicit. I think Mark’s answer is better, though, as it should preserve all tags, not just the ones GDAL knows about.
